# Decode a websocket frame

Tags: websocket, decoding

I am trying to decode a websocket frame, but I'm not successful when it comes to decoding the extended payload. Here what I did achieve so far:

```
char *in = data;
char *buffer;
unsigned int i;
unsigned char mask[4];
unsigned int packet_length = 0;
int rc;

/* Expect a finished text frame. */
assert(in[0] == '\x81');
packet_length = ((unsigned char) in[1]) & 0x7f;

mask[0] = in[2];
mask[1] = in[3];
mask[2] = in[4];
mask[3] = in[5];

if (packet_length <= 125) {           **// This decoding works**
     /* Unmask the payload. */
    for (i = 0; i < packet_length; i++)
        in[6 + i] ^= mask[i % 4];
    rc = asprintf(&buffer, "%.*s", packet_length, in + 6);
} else
    if (packet_length == 126) {       **//This decosing does NOT work**
        /* Unmask the payload. */
        for (i = 0; i < packet_length; i++)
          in[8 + i] ^= mask[i % 4];
        rc = asprintf(&buffer, "%.*s", packet_length, in + 8);
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I encode the extended payload?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If packet_length is 126, the following 2 bytes give the length of data to be read.

If packet_length is 127, the following 8 bytes give the length of data to be read.

The mask is contained in the following 4 bytes (after the length).

The message to be decoded follows this.

The [data framing section](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-hybi-thewebsocketprotocol-17#section-5) of the spec has a useful illustration of this.

If you re-order your code to something like

- Read packet_length
- Check for packet_length of 126 or 127.  Reassign packet_length to value of following 2/4 bytes if required.
- Read mask (the 4 bytes after packet_length, including any additional 2 or 8 bytes read for the step above).
- Decode message (everything after the mask).

then things should work.

Comment: made a small correction: 127 in the length means the following 8 bytes hold the payload length (not 4)

Comment: Just curious why the size of the length field becomes 8 when payload length is 127?  what if the payload length is 128 or 1000?  Thought it would be 8 when payload length > 126, no?

Answer (score 13):

The sticking point is at > 125 bytes payload.

The format is pretty simple, lets say you send ten a's in JavaScript:

```
ws.send("a".repeat(10))
```

Then the server will receive:

```
bytes[16]=818a8258a610e339c771e339c771e339
```

- byte 0: The 0x81 is just an indicator that a message received
- byte 1: the 0x8a is the length, substract 0x80 from it, 0x0A == 10
- byte 2, 3, 4, 5: the 4 byte xor key to decrypt the payload
- the rest: payload

But now lets say you send 126 a's in JavaScript:

```
ws.send("a".repeat(126))
```

Then the server will receive:

```
bytes[134]=81fe007ee415f1e5857490848574908485749084857490848574908485749084857490848574908485749084857490848574908485749084857490848574908485749084857490848574908485749084857490848574908485749084857490848574908485749084857490848574908485749084857490848574908485749084857490848574
```

If the length of the payload is > 125, the byte 1 will have the value 0xfe, the format changes then to:

- byte 0: The 0x81 is just an indicator that a message received
- byte 1: will be 0xfe
- byte 2, 3: the length of the payload as a uint16 number
- byte 4, 5, 6, 7: the 4 byte xor key to decrypt the payload
- the rest: payload

Example code in C#:

```
List<byte[]> decodeWebsocketFrame(Byte[] bytes)
{
    List<Byte[]> ret = new List<Byte[]>();
    int offset = 0;
    while (offset + 6 < bytes.Length)
    {
        // format: 0==ascii/binary 1=length-0x80, byte 2,3,4,5=key, 6+len=message, repeat with offset for next...
        int len = bytes[offset + 1] - 0x80;

        if (len <= 125)
        {

            //String data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
            //Debug.Log("len=" + len + "bytes[" + bytes.Length + "]=" + ByteArrayToString(bytes) + " data[" + data.Length + "]=" + data);
            Debug.Log("len=" + len + " offset=" + offset);
            Byte[] key = new Byte[] { bytes[offset + 2], bytes[offset + 3], bytes[offset + 4], bytes[offset + 5] };
            Byte[] decoded = new Byte[len];
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            {
                int realPos = offset + 6 + i;
                decoded[i] = (Byte)(bytes[realPos] ^ key[i % 4]);
            }
            offset += 6 + len;
            ret.Add(decoded);
        } else
        {
            int a = bytes[offset + 2];
            int b = bytes[offset + 3];
            len = (a << 8) + b;
            //Debug.Log("Length of ws: " + len);

            Byte[] key = new Byte[] { bytes[offset + 4], bytes[offset + 5], bytes[offset + 6], bytes[offset + 7] };
            Byte[] decoded = new Byte[len];
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            {
                int realPos = offset + 8 + i;
                decoded[i] = (Byte)(bytes[realPos] ^ key[i % 4]);
            }

            offset += 8 + len;
            ret.Add(decoded);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Please do not do arithmetic with Hex!

Comment: @Andrew why not ? Hex is just a way to represent a number. I had no particular problem to use it, and sometimes, specially for protocol parsing, is very useful