# Tomcat7.0.37 Websocket sends 0x81 0x00 0x11

Tags: c#, java, tomcat, websocket

I'm using [websocket-sharp](https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp) to try to talk to a Tomcat7 websocket using their webchat example. Using a browser and the js chat web client included on the apache website (`http://localhost:8080/examples/websocket/chat.html`) I am able to chat back and forth, but when I try in C# I get errors trying to grab the websocket frame whenever the server sends a message. I have been able to send messages from the client just fine though.

The stream that is messing me up is:

`0x81 0x00 0x11`

I have looked here: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-hybi-thewebsocketprotocol-17#section-5, but I'm not sure why Apache is sending that byte stream. I've added breakpoints in both C# and tomcat and when it sends the message to the browser, it makes it there intact, but when it reaches the C# app, I get a three-byte string. Here's another one:

`0x81 0x00 0x20`

Does anyone know why this is happening?

[There's also this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9182350/decode-a-websocket-frame) that describes what should happen when the length is 126 and 127, but 0x81 is 129... so confused.

Is this a bug?

Comment: if `0x81 0x00` are the first two bytes of a frame, it means a text message of length 0, i.e. an empty text message. that's pretty odd. the next byte `0x11/20` would be illegal start of next frame (unless some extensions are at work, which I highly doubt)